# Using unicode with SQLAlchemy and Pyramid

Tags: python, unicode, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I have a `textbox`, a `button` and a `search` function. In the search function I get a request from `textbox` and using:

```
queryE = queryE.filter(queryE.Campaign.CampaignName.like("%"+CampaignsKeyWord+"%"))
```

If the keyword is just ***latin*** encoding, the result is ok, but when I enter ***unicode*** (for example, Chinese or Japanese), it doesn't work.

For example `おはようございます` is my string in db ok? When I type `います` to search it will compare and give me `おはようございます` result, right? But doesn't. When I print `おはようございます`, I can see `ã?Šã?¯ã‚ˆã?†ã?”ã?–ã?„ã?¾ã?™` in the screen

Comment: You'll have to be more specific. What doesn't work? What do you see, and what did you expect to see? What kind of input did you give for each case, exactly?

Comment: For example おはようございます is my string in db ok?

Comment: You need to [edit] your question, add both request input, database contents, and what you got from the database, and what you expected. Without that information, we cannot help you.

Answer (score 1):

That is the UTF-8 bytes of `おはようございます` treated as Windows-1252. Typical with a windows terminal or web page with unset content type charset. But you don't have to worry, your program is outputting valid UTF-8, just compare them:

What you see converted to Windows-1252:

```
e3 3f 8a e3 3f af e3 82 88 e3 3f 86 e3 3f 94 e3 3f 96 e3 3f 84 e3 3f be e3 3f 99
```

Expected result in UTF-8:

```
e3 81 8a e3 81 af e3 82 88 e3 81 86 e3 81 94 e3 81 96 e3 81 84 e3 81 be e3 81 99
```

The only difference here is `0x3f` (`"?"`) instead of `0x81`, this is because `0x81` is undefined for Windows-1252.

---

It's just a question of declaring the used encoding to the receiving end, with pyramid you can do:

```
response.charset = 'utf8'
```

Note that this is with a web page, if you mean windows terminal just forget about it.

Answer (score 1):

If your Pyramid template or response for that page doesn't have the correct character encoding set it can cause the text to become garbled.  I could be wrong, yet from the information provided it sounds like it has more to do with the HTML document than Pyramid or SQLAlchemy.  If Python had a problem decoding text such as Japanese, it would likely raise UnicodeDecodeError for example, rather than trying to output the text garbled.

If you are using a template in Pyramid, such as Chameleon, it may have the wrong encoding set in it's meta tag.  If so, try switching to 'utf-8' in the template similar to:

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
```